# Complex cosine with exponent equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm tasked with solving the equation $$\cos(\pi e^z)=0$$.

What I've done so far is use $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, substitute $w=e^{i \pi e^z}$, get $w=0$ and $w=-1$ and using $$w=e^{iz}=e^{-y+ix}=e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i \sin(x))$$

I get that $|w|=|e^{-y}|=1$ so $(cos(x)+i\sin(x))=-1$ or $x=\pi+n2\pi$.

I'm new to complex numbers, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions are given by $$\pi e^z= \tfrac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$$ for integral $k$. So
$$e^z=\tfrac12 + k=\tfrac{2k+1}{2}$$
For $k\geq 0$, this gives the solutions
$$z = \ln\tfrac{2k+1}{2} + 2n\pi i$$
for integral $n$ and for $k<0$ this gives the solutions
$$z = \ln -\tfrac{2k+1}{2} + (2n+1)\pi i$$
for integral $n$. (Here, "$\ln$" is the familiar real-valued function of a positive variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi e^z=u$. We have:
$$
\cos u=\frac{e^{iu}+e^{-iu}}{2}=0 \quad \rightarrow
$$
$$
\left(e^{iu} \right)^2+1=0 \quad \rightarrow \quad e^{iu}=\pm i \quad \rightarrow \quad u=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
$$
this gives

$$
e^z=\pm \frac{1}{2}+2k
$$

and you can find $z$ using the principal value of the logarithm.